# how to create a xerces 3.1.1 xcode project on mac osx 10.7.5

Tags: xcode, xerces, xerces-c

Can anyone please let me know how to create xerces 3.1.1 xcode project on mac.

I have downloaded the xercese 3.1.1 source code from xerces site. The source code only include projects related to windows.

Thanks,
RCJ

Comment: What in particular is the problem creating the project?

Comment: Actually i need to import xerces 3.1.1 source code to xcode project.I tried by including the source code and headers, but lots of error are appearing. Some headers present are window only, i can't put check for MACOS to exclude that headers as xerces is third party source code

Comment: Why not just compile xerces as a static library and install it in `/usr/local` or `/opt/local` and just use it from your Xcode-based project?

Comment: Static Library would not be fine. I want to create xerces framework to export headers. so that other customer can use that exported headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem fixed.

Tallied source file to be included in Xcode project with the file already got compiled through make.

Removed unnecessary inclusion of c files from projects.
At the end project build successfully